# Web scraping multiple urls with Scrapy and storing the result

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape reviews and countries from the three links of the hotels with Scrapy but I am stuck with the storing the result properly. The reviews and countries from every link are stored in a row(columns are ok, I got two columns). So, I get only three rows when I store the result in csv. But I would like to get every review in another row, for example if there are 6 reviews in a link, accordingly to get 6 rows while storing in csv. How can I solve this issue in order to get that kind of result?

I used the codes as following:

```
`import scrapy
 import re
 from scrapy import Request
 import json
 from ..items import BakuRevItem

class BakuReviewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'baku_reviews'
allowed_domains = ['booking.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
        'https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/smith-boutique-3rd.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=1&hapos=1&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=913585406_364184384_1_1_0&highlighted_blocks=913585406_364184384_1_1_0&matching_block_id=913585406_364184384_1_1_0&sr_pri_blocks=913585406_364184384_1_1_0__4845&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults#hotelTmpl',
        'https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/the-merchant-baku.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=2&hapos=2&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&highlighted_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&matching_block_id=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0__14000&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults#hotelTmpl',
        'https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/sabir-ogli-guest-house.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=3&hapos=3&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&highlighted_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&matching_block_id=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0__4240&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults#hotelTmpl',
       
    ]
    
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
    
        items=BakuRevItem()
    
        all_items=response.xpath("//div[@id='bodyconstraint']/div")
        for x in all_items:
            reviews=x.xpath(".//div[@class='db29ecfbe2 c688f151a2']/text()").extract()
            countries=x.xpath(".//span[@class='a5499473ab f01b03907b']/text()").extract()
        
            items['reviews']=reviews
            items['countries']=countries
        
            yield items`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over each review individually to extract its information and yield the singular review information one at a time, in order to get all of the reviews on their own rows.

For example:

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy import Request
import json

class BakuReviewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'baku_reviews'
    allowed_domains = ['booking.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
        'https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/smith-boutique-3rd.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=1&hapos=1&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=913585406_364184384_1_1_0&highlighted_blocks=913585406_364184384_1_1_0&matching_block_id=913585406_364184384_1_1_0&sr_pri_blocks=913585406_364184384_1_1_0__4845&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults#hotelTmpl',
        'https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/the-merchant-baku.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=2&hapos=2&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&highlighted_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&matching_block_id=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0__14000&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults#hotelTmpl',
        'https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/sabir-ogli-guest-house.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=3&hapos=3&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&highlighted_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&matching_block_id=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0__4240&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults#hotelTmpl',

    ]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):


        # all_items=response.xpath("//div[@id='bodyconstraint']/div")
        for x in response.xpath("//li[@class='d5fc932504 ebb6d69bfc']"):
            items={}
            reviews=x.xpath(".//div[@class='db29ecfbe2 c688f151a2']/text()").get()
            countries=x.xpath(".//span[@class='a5499473ab f01b03907b']/text()").get()

            items['reviews']=reviews
            items['countries']=countries

            yield items
```

output

```
As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=
1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=1&hapos=1&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=913585406_364184384_1_1_0&highlighted_blocks=913585406_36418
4384_1_1_0&matching_block_id=913585406_364184384_1_1_0&sr_pri_blocks=913585406_364184384_1_1_0__4845&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults#hotelTmpl> (referer: None)
2023-03-10 20:46:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/smith-boutique-3rd.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4
As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=
1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=1&hapos=1&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=913585406_364184384_1_1_0&highlighted_blocks=913585406_36418
4384_1_1_0&matching_block_id=913585406_364184384_1_1_0&sr_pri_blocks=913585406_364184384_1_1_0__4845&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'Location, staff and breakfast is very nice.  Rooms are clean, cozy.', 'countries': 'Azerbaijan'}
2023-03-10 20:46:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/smith-boutique-3rd.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4
As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=
1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=1&hapos=1&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=913585406_364184384_1_1_0&highlighted_blocks=913585406_36418
4384_1_1_0&matching_block_id=913585406_364184384_1_1_0&sr_pri_blocks=913585406_364184384_1_1_0__4845&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'Все понравилось. Уютные номера, приличный, отзывчивый персонал.', 'countries': 'Azerbaijan'}
2023-03-10 20:46:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/smith-boutique-3rd.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4
As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=
1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=1&hapos=1&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=913585406_364184384_1_1_0&highlighted_blocks=913585406_36418
4384_1_1_0&matching_block_id=913585406_364184384_1_1_0&sr_pri_blocks=913585406_364184384_1_1_0__4845&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': None, 'countries': None}
2023-03-10 20:46:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/smith-boutique-3rd.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4
As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=
1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=1&hapos=1&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=913585406_364184384_1_1_0&highlighted_blocks=913585406_36418
4384_1_1_0&matching_block_id=913585406_364184384_1_1_0&sr_pri_blocks=913585406_364184384_1_1_0__4845&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': None, 'countries': None}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/the-merchant-baku.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4A
s3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1
&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=2&hapos=2&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&highlighted_blocks=616140807_242317
948_2_2_0&matching_block_id=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0__14000&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults#hotelTmpl> (referer: None)
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/the-merchant-baku.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4A
s3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1
&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=2&hapos=2&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&highlighted_blocks=616140807_242317
948_2_2_0&matching_block_id=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0__14000&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'it had a nearby variety of restaurants. they took the trouble of giving us a double bed instead of two twin beds. there were two big cushions and one small cushion per person in bed. H
ouse cleaning people were very helpful, cheerful and caring...', 'countries': 'Kuwait'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/the-merchant-baku.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4A
s3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1
&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=2&hapos=2&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&highlighted_blocks=616140807_242317
948_2_2_0&matching_block_id=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0__14000&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'Excellent rooms and service. Staff is friendly and courteous. Food is fantastic especially when we talk about breakfast. They have kept adequate variety of food that an average person
would eat. In some hotels, we see a lot of breakfast spread out...', 'countries': 'India'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/the-merchant-baku.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4A
s3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1
&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=2&hapos=2&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&highlighted_blocks=616140807_242317
948_2_2_0&matching_block_id=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0__14000&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'very nice architecture and room design, friendly staff and amazing location! plenty or restaurants and cafés downstairs!', 'countries': 'United Arab Emirates'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/the-merchant-baku.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4A
s3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1
&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=2&hapos=2&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&highlighted_blocks=616140807_242317
948_2_2_0&matching_block_id=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0__14000&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'The Merchant Baku is everything you need in Baku - central location, a well thought and decorated hotel, fantastic breakfast and their restaurant food is not to be missed either. The r
ooms are crafted perfectly to enjoy Baku the best way you can!...', 'countries': 'United Arab Emirates'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/the-merchant-baku.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4A
s3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1
&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=2&hapos=2&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&highlighted_blocks=616140807_242317
948_2_2_0&matching_block_id=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0__14000&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'it was a such a wonderful  place and great experience ask about Emin he will help about the price and he gave us for our extend night amazing discount for balcony room', 'countries': '
United Arab Emirates'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/the-merchant-baku.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4A
s3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1
&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=2&hapos=2&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&highlighted_blocks=616140807_242317
948_2_2_0&matching_block_id=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0__14000&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'Since I arrived at the hotel at 11 am, the room was ready and a warm welcome\nThe hotel is in a very excellent location and has two exits in front of the old market and behind Nizami S
treet, with the availability of cafes and restaurants\nAll of the...', 'countries': 'United Arab Emirates'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/the-merchant-baku.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4A
s3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1
&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=2&hapos=2&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&highlighted_blocks=616140807_242317
948_2_2_0&matching_block_id=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0__14000&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'Everything is excellent in this hotel ( location, staff , room , clean )', 'countries': 'Kuwait'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/the-merchant-baku.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4A
s3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1
&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=2&hapos=2&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&highlighted_blocks=616140807_242317
948_2_2_0&matching_block_id=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0__14000&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'Beautiful hotel in central location with attentive employees. We had a wonderful stay', 'countries': 'Singapore'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/the-merchant-baku.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4A
s3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1
&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=2&hapos=2&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&highlighted_blocks=616140807_242317
948_2_2_0&matching_block_id=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0__14000&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'definitely best hotel ever in baku, nice staff and nice service \nthe hotel location close to everything you need old city and nizami street', 'countries': 'United Arab Emirates'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/the-merchant-baku.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4A
s3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adults=1
&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=2&hapos=2&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&highlighted_blocks=616140807_242317
948_2_2_0&matching_block_id=616140807_242317948_2_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=616140807_242317948_2_2_0__14000&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'Friendly, welcoming staff. Check-in efficient and fast. The room was well-appointed. plenty of room. And now in hindsight the blackout curtains were a nicety! If you had a room on the
alleyway, the music stopped by about 23:00.  Most of the time...', 'countries': 'United Arab Emirates'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/sabir-ogli-guest-house.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGo
AgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adu
lts=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=3&hapos=3&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&highlighted_blocks=181570004_3
57983111_0_2_0&matching_block_id=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0__4240&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults#hotelTmpl> (referer: None)
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/sabir-ogli-guest-house.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGo
AgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adu
lts=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=3&hapos=3&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&highlighted_blocks=181570004_3
57983111_0_2_0&matching_block_id=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0__4240&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'The location was so great. I will recommend to book this place if you travel Baku. They were accommodating and very helpful.', 'countries': 'United Arab Emirates'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/sabir-ogli-guest-house.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGo
AgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adu
lts=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=3&hapos=3&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&highlighted_blocks=181570004_3
57983111_0_2_0&matching_block_id=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0__4240&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'Its in the center \nStaff are amazing \nMusic around the hotel make it so enjoyable', 'countries': 'Oman'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/sabir-ogli-guest-house.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGo
AgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adu
lts=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=3&hapos=3&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&highlighted_blocks=181570004_3
57983111_0_2_0&matching_block_id=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0__4240&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'Located in city center and near by attractive locations and many restaurant around', 'countries': 'Qatar'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/sabir-ogli-guest-house.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGo
AgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adu
lts=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=3&hapos=3&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&highlighted_blocks=181570004_3
57983111_0_2_0&matching_block_id=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0__4240&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'the best location, reasonably priced and friendly staff', 'countries': 'United Arab Emirates'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/sabir-ogli-guest-house.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGo
AgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adu
lts=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=3&hapos=3&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&highlighted_blocks=181570004_3
57983111_0_2_0&matching_block_id=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0__4240&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'in the middle of every thing. neat and clean. it’s worth your money. can really enjoy your holidays and relax. \nI loved daily going to the icheri shahar and Baku promenade hardly 150m
trs.', 'countries': 'Bahrain'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/sabir-ogli-guest-house.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGo
AgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adu
lts=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=3&hapos=3&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&highlighted_blocks=181570004_3
57983111_0_2_0&matching_block_id=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0__4240&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'The customer service was great! as well as the cleanliness in the hotel room was just beyond perfect!', 'countries': 'United Arab Emirates'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/sabir-ogli-guest-house.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGo
AgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adu
lts=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=3&hapos=3&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&highlighted_blocks=181570004_3
57983111_0_2_0&matching_block_id=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0__4240&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'Located at the city center. Near to restaurants, shops and bars, boulevard and metro station. Also with strong wifi and clean rooms as well. Plus accomodating and cool receptionists',
'countries': 'United Arab Emirates'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/sabir-ogli-guest-house.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGo
AgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adu
lts=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=3&hapos=3&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&highlighted_blocks=181570004_3
57983111_0_2_0&matching_block_id=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0__4240&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'The location is Awesome. You Can say Heart of Baku.', 'countries': 'Saudi Arabia'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/sabir-ogli-guest-house.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGo
AgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adu
lts=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=3&hapos=3&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&highlighted_blocks=181570004_3
57983111_0_2_0&matching_block_id=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0__4240&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'very good location, near to different tourist spots. Our view from the window is really great. Staff are very helpful too', 'countries': 'United Arab Emirates'}
2023-03-10 20:46:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.booking.com/hotel/az/sabir-ogli-guest-house.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBGIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGo
AgO4As3BpqAGwAIB0gIkMmY0NzdhYjUtMmI1ZS00ZDhmLWE4MmItNmQ0NDAzZjY1NjAy2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&ucfs=1&arphpl=1&checkin=2023-03-30&checkout=2023-03-31&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&group_adults=1&req_adu
lts=1&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&req_children=0&hpos=3&hapos=3&sr_order=popularity&srpvid=a11c4acfdab8035a&srepoch=1678358305&all_sr_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&highlighted_blocks=181570004_3
57983111_0_2_0&matching_block_id=181570004_357983111_0_2_0&sr_pri_blocks=181570004_357983111_0_2_0__4240&tpi_r=2&from_sustainable_property_sr=1&from=searchresults>
{'reviews': 'The hospitality was amazing and the room was beautiful, clean and well furnished. Definitely going to stay here again.', 'countries': 'United Kingdom'}
```